# Chaining functions: Creating .post variable from on click event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm attempting to create a post value from an on click event.

From here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        var pastDATE = $(this).text();  
            alert(pastDATE);
        }); //end click
    }); //end ready
```

I've tried numerous variations on the following code in attempt to get the post variable to work but am obviously missing something critical.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        var pastDATE = $(this).text.post("CalendarFunction.php", function() {
             alert("success");
             })
            .done(function() {
                alert("second success");
                    })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("error" );
                    })
            .always(function() {
                alert("finished");
            });
         });
```

The error console is telling me I have an undefined object. Can someone show me how to fix this?

Comment: what are you trying to do? how are you trying to use `$(this).text()`?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the data pulled with $(this).text() as POST data to a php script. *edited extra words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotten the `pastDATE` successfully now you just have to send it with your post request.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

the second param of the jquery.post is the data to be sent

```
var pastDATE = $(this).text()
$.post('url', pastDATE, function() {

});
```

What sort of data is your php script expecting? what is the key that it is expecting you might need to key your post value

```
var data = {
  yourKey: pastDATE
}
$.post('url', data, function() {});
```